# Auto generate WPF buttons based on a property in a collection using binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to bind a property in a collection to auto generate buttons, can this be achieved using data binding?

What I tried to do without binding is the following:

```
        var servicesList = sad.GetAllServices().ToList();

        foreach (var service in servicesList)
        {
            var btn = new Button
            {
                Name = "btnService_" + service.Id,
                Content = service.NameEn,
                Width = 200,
                Height = 50,
                Margin = new Thickness(20)
            };

            btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Handling click event...
            };

            PnlServices.Children.Add(btn);
        }
```

I want to create a button for each item in the collection and make the content of the button equal to item.NameEn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Service> servicesList => new ObservableCollection<Service>(sad.GetAllServices().ToList());
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"></local:ViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=servicesList}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                             Width="200"
                             Height="50"
                             Margin="20"
                             Click="OnClickHandler"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First generate collection (Array / List / ObservableCollection) .
2. Bind an ItemsControl Control to the collection in step 1 above to generate buttons.

Note : You cannot bind Name property of a control.

[Good tutorial about ItemsControl](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/itemscontrol/)

Eg;

```
var items = new[] { new { Description = "Btn1" }, new { Description = "Btn2" } };
BtnList.ItemsSource = items;

<ItemsControl x:Name="BtnList">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Description}" />
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `servicesList` to an public `ObservableCollection` and bind to `ListBox` (or `ItemsControl`).

Assuming that your view model is Service.

```
private ObservableCollection<Service> serviceList = new ObservableCollection<Service>();
public ObservableCollection<Service> ServiceList 
{
    get
    {
       return serviceList;
    }
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ServicesList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Height="50" Width="200" Content="{Binding NameEn}" Margin="20" Tag="{Binding Id}" Click="ButtonClickHandler" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</List>
```

Now create a click handler and given change it in xaml for Click event.